# Convert Calendar server UTC time to Calendar local time

Tags: android

I get the timestamp from the server which is in UTC time and do this:

```
public Calendar getSentOnInUTC() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(super.DATE_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            cal.setTime(sdf.parse(this.sentOn));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            UDebug.printExceptionStackTrace(e);
            //*meh*
        }
        return cal;
    }
```

Now, I would like to convert the time inside the returned Calendar to the local timezone of the device. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Date date = utcFormat.parse("2018-03-04T21:21:21.038Z");

DateFormat pstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
pstFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
```

And `pstFormat.format(date)` to return your local time.
PST you can replace with your timezone.